# Using prompted variable with StartsWith

Tags: powershell

I am trying to stop a specific set of services, using .StartsWith to find them.

```
Get-Service | ForEach {
    $name = $_.Name

    if ($name.StartsWith("FooBar")) {
        # stop service
        if ($_.Status -ne "Stopped") {
            Stop-Service "$name" -Force
            $_.WaitForStatus('Stopped', '00:01:00')
            Write-Host "Service $name stopped."
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine - services FooBarBinglyBong and FooBarJingleJangle will be stopped. However when I try and do this:

```
[string] $input = Read-Host -prompt 'Stop services starting with'

Get-Service | ForEach {
    $name = $_.Name

    if ($name.StartsWith("$input")) {
    ...
```

It stops every single service. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing $input to $input2 works.

My fault for using a reserved word I guess.